# Any mean to filter dataview with a custom function?

Tags: c#

I tried to filter dataview with a custom function but it isn't recognized. Is it possible ? If yes any article ?

Comment: Yes, you can filter DataView records. Perhaps you can post your code that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a custom function as a `RowFilter` in a `DataView`, you can only use an expression as defined in the documentation for the `DataColumn.Expression` property.  There's a lot you can do in the context of an expression, so that's usually sufficient.

A quick and dirty workaround, in case your function does something that can't be done in an expression, is to add a temporary column and filter on it:

```
dv.Table.Columns.Add("Flag", typeof(bool));
foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
{
   dr.SetField("Flag", myFunction(dr);
}
dv.RowFilter = "Flag = True";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of various filters for a DataView named dv:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Country = 'USA'";
dv.RowFilter = "EmployeeID >5 AND Birthdate < #1/31/82#"
dv.RowFilter = "Description LIKE '*product*'"
dv.RowFilter = "employeeID IN (2,4,5)"
```

The names before the equal sign are names of columns, or fields, in the DataView.

Answer (score 1):

you could [use a CollectionView](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=31), this would allow for grouping, filtering, etc.  It will work with DataTables/DataSets

```
DataTable table = MyDataSet["MyDataTable"]
ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(table );
collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterOutA);
```